# Sagging floor cause for concern?

Tags: truss

In a townhouse where my second floor sags in all kinds of directions - do i need to have it checked out/fixed, and by whom?

Rough estimates:
Age: 34 years old
Width of unit: 21ft
Second floor held up by a clear span of open web trusses, believe to be about 24” on center spacing. Not sure of truss depth.
There is a wall that runs perpendicular down most of the length of the unit (and thus also perpendicular to the trusses) that is about 8 ft from one side. In other words, space is split 8 and 13 for 21 total.
13 ft side is a bedroom, 8 ft side is bath and walk in closet.

Floor sags towards this wall in the middle from both sides.

Sagging very noticeable in the bathroom; there is a vanity along one wall where when i put a 4ft level at the toekick, i have to raise it about 1 3/8” to get the level to be level. The floor also has a curve to it, by which i mean there is a gap between the floor and level.

Similar in closet, where i installed a closet system that hangs on a rail, with vertical panels that go to the floor. The panels at the end wall are on the floor, but the panels at the wall in the middle are 1 1/4” off the floor.

Possibly related, but i feel like other areas of the house are sagging also; i have a window in this bedroom that starts about 2ft from the end wall and is 6 ft wide. The window looks level but the window sill is sloped down in the direction of the middle wall.

Comment: Is it possible they are not sagging but were built unlevel? How old is the building?

Comment: About 34 years old

Comment: I would want to inspect the foundation / exterior walls for damage in my area carpenter ants and termites cause structural damage and my experience is it is worse on external walls.